# Removing Last Comma in JSON

Tags: php, json, curl

I tried the previous solutions here but my problem still persists.

When I make json_decode($result) the response I get with cURL, I get "NULL".

When I do var_dump($response), the string type response is as follows.

As far as I understand, this problem occurs because of the comma in the last part.

My response (in string type):

```
{
  "returnCode": "0",
  "returnMessage": "bla bla bla message",
  "fast": "H",
}
```

Comment: Please can you [edit] the question to include links to the "previous solutions" you refer to; or better yet, to a [mcve] of the code that you've tried, and the result you get.

Comment: You should fix this at the source. A comma at the end is not valid JSON.

Comment: This implies that the source isn't using a proper JSON library to create it, which will likely lead to other problems. You should fix that, not try to work around it like this.

Answer (score 1):

A `str_replace` could work here:

```php
$cleaned_response = str_replace($response, ",\n}", "}");
```

You just need to make sure you get the newline character right.

Comment: But all you care about is the last comma and newline.  That shouldn't change.  If it does, then you're accessing an unstable API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_last_error()` to find about the eventual eror when using `json_decode()`.

But no matter what, you are right : the response you get is not a valid JSON, it must not have this last comma.

Example here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21c25760f21c5d33dc7f0c6397161fa4a26b3b81